# cannot build install opencv4.5.5 for ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python3, 22.04, opencv

I am trying to build install opencv4.5.5 with cuda10.6 on ubuntu 22.04.
Followed every step in this tutorial
https://www.sproutworkshop.com/2022/02/how-to-compile-opencv-4-5-5-with-cuda-11-6-and-cudnn-8-3-2-on-ubuntu-22-04-daily-build/

I was able to install CUDA, cudnn however opencv cmake does not seem to detect python3 properly as below

[image]

This is what it should be look like when tried cmake on ubuntu 20.04
[image]

I don't see any python entry here and when finished make install, python does not find cv2 as below

```
$ python3 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)" Traceback (most
recent call last):   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Any idea how to let opencv recognize python3.10 properly?

Answer (score 0):

The link you have attached redirects to 404 not found! It looks like that article was deleted due to an improper installation guide.

However, you can install OpenCV on Ubuntu 22.04 using the **Python** simply.
You only need to install [python](https://itslinuxfoss.com/install-python-three-nine-ubuntu/) first then

```
sudo apt install python3-opencv -y
```

To confirm the installation of OpenCV by the above-executed command, we will display its version:

```
python3 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"
```

If you don't want to do it using python then you can also install OpenCV on Ubuntu 22.04 using the Github

You can read about both methods in detail on: https://itslinuxfoss.com/guide-install-opencv-ubuntu/